# Dynamic configuration in Django

Tags: python, django, web-services

I am trying to have some configuration settings in Django be automatically determined at runtime.

I have set up a middleware handler that runs once, before the first request is made, and then disables itself by raising MiddlewareNotUsed. When the handler runs, it pulls some information from another server via HTTP. I would like to have that information become available for use in all views.

In the settings module, I have an empty string. I thought that I would be able to dynamically modify this with the retrieved information, so that it would become available to all the views. But when I update the string from the middleware handler, the information is somehow lost. The views see only the empty string.

How would I make the information that was retrieved over HTTP available to all the views?

I would like to keep it in memory, not in a database or on the filesystem, though I will use one of those options if that is the only choice.

Comment: u could use django cache to store the string that way it will be available in all views

Comment: You can use this app: https://github.com/niwibe/django-dbconf </spam>

Comment: You can also use request.session which is more reliable than cache

Comment: @alexarsh: Could you outline how this would work? There is no request object available when the startup middleware handler runs.

Comment: Define a class in middleware (class CustomMiddleware(object)). In that class define process_request function (def process_request(self, request)) and then you can use session like: request.session["key"] = ...

Comment: @alexarsh: I've read up on Django sessions, and they don't look like they're a fit for this. While I'm trying to share data out to all views, sessions are designed to keep connection specific information. So, as far as I can tell, the custom middleware you are suggesting would have to run for each new request and copy the information out to that connection. And the custom middleware would still need some mechanism to hold the data I want to make available to the views. In addition, sessions are implemented with cookies in the background, which I can't use for this.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I did something similar once and I'm not very proud of it :)

But it's quite simple and did the job, so here it is:

```
from django.conf import settings

class SomeMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        try:
            settings.SOME_STRING_CONFIG
        except AttributeError:
            settings.SOME_STRING_CONFIG = some_value_to_set
```

However, this is not a nice way to treat django.settings, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#altering-settings-at-runtime.

No, let me quote it here:

> Altering settings at runtime
>   You **shouldn't** alter settings in your applications at runtime. For example, **don't** do this in a view:
>
> from django.conf import settings
>       settings.DEBUG = True   # **Don't** do this!
>
> **The only place you should assign to settings is in a settings file.**

(I added the bold)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This works for me. The difference between this and what I had already implemented is assigning to django.conf.settings instead of the project specific settings. It's unfortunate that the Django docs discourage this without saying why and without offering an alternative. I think they may be talking about using this as a mechanism for sharing information between views, which sounds like it could be very risky. I can imagine that using this could cause a race condition even for my use case, so I am going to leave the question open. (Sorry about that.)

Comment: Yeah, I tell myself that if I alter the settings in an early-on (preferably first) middleware, than it's ok :)

Comment: Note this works because it sets the value only once. You shouldn't alter settings per request this way for example because that would not be thread safe.